# Web Service random timeout / dropping connections

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, iis

We have a windows client application that makes web service calls.  The web service can sometimes perform rather long queries on a database.  We have 3 production environments where this works fine.  However, on one of them we receive this error when performing those long running queries through the webservice.  The client sees;

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

This happens often, but does not generally happen when there are no users who are using the web service (i.e: when we test at night time). Only during the daytime when the web service is under load.

If we turn ON the http-keepalives setting, the exact error still occurs, only the text is different.  It will say;

> "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server."

All timeouts seem to be ok (client web service proxy, web.config, IIS). Any info anyone could give with this would be much appriciated!

The system runs SQL 2008 R2 Express on 64bit Windows server 2008 R2, and Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.4963

The other systems that run without this issue are using 32bit Windows server 2003 R2,SQL 2008 Express (not R2) and Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.3053

Comment: Fixed by disabling response pinging in ISS web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by disabling response pinging in ISS web site